# Rename all .txt files inside subfolders with "find"

Tags: command-line, bash, batch-rename

I want to rename all `.txt` files inside a folder. This rename do rename all `.txt` for me:

```
rename 's/\.txt//g' *.txt -v
```

but when I want to rename all sub folders with

```
find ./ -type d -execdir rename 's/\.txt//g' *.txt -v ";"
```

It shows me:

```
Can't rename *.txt *: No such file or directory
Can't rename *.txt *: No such file or directory
...
```

Also `find ./ -type -d` shows me current and all sub folders correctly.

Why I have `No such file or directory` message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `find`'s `-exec` syntax correctly, using `'{}'` to represent the found files

```
find ./ -type d -name '*.txt' -execdir rename -n 's/\.txt//g' '{}' \;
```

Remove `-n` after `rename` once you've tested it.

(assuming you really did want to change directory names and not regular file names - if that was the case, use `-type f` instead of `type -d`)

Comment: Thank you so much. I wanted to rename just file names. works perfectly.

Comment: @ICE it's a pleasure :D

Comment: Just a small mention. I reached this page searching for how to rename all ".srt" files in the current directory and subdirectories to ".txt". Right now I'm looking at the man pages to understand the intricacies of the `find` command, but just to save others time, it'd be nice if you could explain the meaning of the commands. Else I'll post once I've understood it.

Comment: Ok figured it out `find . -name "*.srt" -exec rename 's/.srt$/.txt/' {} \;` will convert all srt files in the current and sub-directories to txt. The `find` commands lists out all the file names. `exec` is for executing a command (in this case `rename`). The `s` and `$` appear to be Perl regular expressions.